# Screen capture software that streams to Apple TV?

Tags: screen-capture, streaming, screen-sharing

Is there any application that can stream content of a screen, or application window to Apple TV? I would like something that works in similar fashion as AirFoil, but for captured screen content instead of sound.

What I am looking for is a way to skip to have projector and cables in our conference room. Instead of going with a projector and having to mount it to the ceiling and have long cables, I would go with a big TV, Apple TV and than simply stream video from a Mac laptop to Apple TV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ability to stream content of your screen to Apple TV is coming in [Mountain Lion](http://www.apple.com/macosx/mountain-lion/).

Answer (score 2):

Check out Erica Sadun's AirFlick, part of her free AirPlay utilities package. You may have to do some fooling around to get it to send the screen instead of a file, but that should actually be doable with VLC, if she hasn't already built it in.

http://ericasadun.com/ftp/AirPlay/

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but closest thing so far. Thanks!